# Detecting isSticky in Android custom keyboards

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

I have a custom keyboard with buttons that are isSticky enabled but I have problem detecting if it is turned on or off (true / false) and also disabling them after any key is pressed if it is turned on (true).

The problem with this is I can't find a way to detect the keys and also appending the current edittext with the functions (all the sticky buttons has specific functions).

This should happen in the OnKey function,

Here is my keyboard class:

```
public class MyKeyboardListener : Java.Lang.Object, KeyboardView.IOnKeyboardActionListener{

    private readonly Activity _activity;

    public MyKeyboardListener(Activity activity){
        _activity = activity;
    }

    public void OnKey(Android.Views.Keycode primaryCode, Android.Views.Keycode[] keyCodes){
        var eventTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        var keyEvent = new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime, KeyEventActions.Down, primaryCode, 0);

        switch ((int)primaryCode) {
            case 1005:
            break;

            case 1006:
            break;

            default:
                _activity.DispatchKeyEvent(keyEvent);
            break;
        }
    }

    public void OnPress(Android.Views.Keycode primaryCode){
    }

    public void OnRelease(Android.Views.Keycode primaryCode){
    }

    public void OnText(Java.Lang.ICharSequence text){
    }

    public void SwipeDown(){
    }

    public void SwipeLeft(){
    }

    public void SwipeRight(){
    }

    public void SwipeUp(){
    }
}
```

Keyboard.axml

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keyWidth="100%"
android:keyHeight="6%p">
<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="1000"
        android:keyLabel="A"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:isModifier="true" 
        android:isSticky="true"
        android:horizontalGap="1%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="1001"
        android:keyLabel="B"
        android:isModifier="true" 
        android:isSticky="true"
        android:horizontalGap="1%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="1002"
        android:keyLabel="C"
        android:isModifier="true" 
        android:isSticky="true"
        android:horizontalGap="1%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="1003"
        android:keyLabel="D"
        android:isModifier="true" 
        android:isSticky="true"
        android:horizontalGap="1%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="1004"
        android:keyLabel="E"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:isModifier="true" 
        android:isSticky="true"
        android:horizontalGap="1%p" />
</Row>
<Row>
    <Key
        android:codes="8"
        android:keyLabel="1"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:horizontalGap="1%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="9"
        android:keyLabel="2"
        android:horizontalGap="1%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="1005"
        android:keyLabel="F"
        android:horizontalGap="1%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="1006"
        android:keyLabel="G46"
        android:horizontalGap="1%p" />
    <Key
        android:codes="67"
        android:keyLabel="DELETE"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:horizontalGap="1%p" />
</Row>
</Keyboard>
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside public class `LatinKeyboardView` extend `KeyboardView`, override `onDraw` method and use the following code to get the sticky and modifiers key

```
List<Key> keys = getKeyboard().getKeys();
for (Key key : keys) {
    Drawable npd;
    // int drawable = R.drawable.btn_normal_with_shadow_t1;
    int drawable = R.drawable.key_normal;
    textColor = sessionManager.getSimpleyKeyTextColor();

    if (key.pressed) {
        drawable = R.drawable.key_normal;
    } else {
        if (key.modifier && key.sticky) {
            drawable = R.drawable.stickey_with_shad_bord;
            textColor = sessionManager.getSimpleyKeyTextColorModifiers();
        } else if (key.modifier) {
            drawable = R.drawable.modifier_btn_with_bord_shad;
            textColor = sessionManager.getSimpleyKeyTextColorModifiers();
        } else {
            drawable = R.drawable.key_normal;
        }
    }
```

here is the xml code where we set modifier to `true`

```
<Key
    android:codes="-1"
    android:isModifier="true"
    android:keyWidth="14.8%p"
    android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
    android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_shift_normal" />
```